# wreath product function in GAP

Tags: gap

Can we compute the wreath product of two arbitrary groups in GAP? There exists the following function : `WreathProduct( G, H[, hom] )`, but I do not how I can use that for two arbitrary groups?

Comment: That function seems to work in precisely the generality that wreath products are defined. Namely, you need to identify $H$ with a subgroup of a permutation group, and that is the role of the hom-part.

Comment: in the case of general linear groups, how does "Hom" work?

Comment: You need to specify hom yourself unless $H$ is already a permutation group (or if you wish to view $H$ as a permutation group in a different way). It does not work differently for general linear groups.

Comment: according to "Hom" I have to find permutation representation of general linear group, and then I will be able to use mentioned  function. righ?

Comment: Yes, that is what the hom will be.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Btw, there were some [changes introduced in GAP 4.7](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/changes/chap2.html): "It is not possible now to call `WreathProduct` with 2nd argument `H` not being a permutation group, without using the 3rd argument specifying the permutation representation. This is an incompatible change but it will produce an error instead of a wrong result. The former behaviour of `WreathProduct` may now be achieved by using `StandardWreathProduct` which returns the wreath product for the (right regular) permutation action of `H` on its elements."

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Ahh, thanks for the heads-up. I thought I had the newest version, but apparently I need to remember to upgrade soon.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Now it's a good time to upgrade :) [GAP 4.7.4 is available!](http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

GAP 4.7 has now two functions for wreath products:

- `WreathProduct` (changed behaviour since GAP 4.7)
- `StandardWreathProduct` (introduced in GAP 4.7)

They are documented in the GAP Manual (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap49.html#X8786EFBC78D7D6ED) or enter in GAP `?WreathProduct` or `?StandardWreathProduct`).

To avoid surprises, it is advised to check which version of GAP you're using.

The changes introduced in GAP 4.7 are described [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/changes/chap2.html), namely:

- It is not possible now to call `WreathProduct` with 2nd argument `H` not being a permutation group, without using the 3rd argument specifying the permutation representation. This is an incompatible change but it will produce an error instead of a wrong result.
- The former behaviour of `WreathProduct` may now be achieved by using `StandardWreathProduct` which returns the wreath product for the (right regular) permutation action of `H` on its elements.

Below there is an example which shows that the results of these two may differ. First we use `StandardWreathProduct`:

```
gap> G:=SmallGroup(32,6);
<pc group of size 32 with 5 generators>
gap> D:=DerivedSubgroup(G);
Group([ f3, f5 ])
gap> S:=StandardWreathProduct(CyclicGroup(2),D);
<group of size 64 with 3 generators>
gap> NilpotencyClassOfGroup(S);
3
gap> IdGroup(S);
[ 64, 138 ]
gap> StructureDescription(S);
"(((C4 x C2) : C2) : C2) : C2"
```

Now we use `WreathProduct` with the 3rd argument computed with `IsomorphismPermGroup(D)`, and obtain another group:

```
gap> G:=SmallGroup(32,6);
<pc group of size 32 with 5 generators>
gap> D:=DerivedSubgroup(G);
Group([ f3, f5 ])
gap> hom:=IsomorphismPermGroup(D);
[ f3, f5 ] -> [ (1,2), (3,4) ]
gap> Image(hom);
Group([ (1,2), (3,4) ])
gap> S:=WreathProduct(CyclicGroup(2),D,hom);
<group of size 64 with 4 generators>
gap> NilpotencyClassOfGroup(S);
2
gap> IdGroup(S);
[ 64, 226 ]
gap> StructureDescription(S);
"D8 x D8"
```

Even more, `IsomorphismPermGroup` is not guaranteed to return the same degree representation at all times, so two different runs on the same group could produce different results. If one constructs `hom` explicitly, then that would be fine.

Finally, the same group as in the first example can be constructed with `WreathProduct` instead of `StandardWreathProduct` using the regular permutation representation:

```
gap> G:=SmallGroup(32,6);
<pc group of size 32 with 5 generators>
gap> D:=DerivedSubgroup(G);
Group([ f3, f5 ])
gap> hom:=ActionHomomorphism(D,AsList(D),OnRight);
<action homomorphism>
gap> Image(hom);
Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4) ])
gap> S:=WreathProduct(CyclicGroup(2),D,hom);
<group of size 64 with 3 generators>
gap> NilpotencyClassOfGroup(S);
3
gap> IdGroup(S);
[ 64, 138 ]
gap> StructureDescription(S);
"(((C4 x C2) : C2) : C2) : C2"
```

---

Comment: I took this particular wreath product from the test file of the GAP package [LAGUNA](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/laguna.html). There is a result in [J.T. Buckley. Polynomial functions and wreath products. Ill. J. Math., 14:274-282, 1970] that the nilpotency class of the wreath product $C_p \wr H$ is equal to $t(H)$ - the nilpotency index of the augmentation ideal of the group ring $F_p H$. The latter index may be computed with LAGUNA package using the formula which involves indices of `JenningsSeries` of $H$, and it reports 3, not 2:

```
gap> F:=GF(2);
GF(2)
gap> FD:=GroupRing(F,D);
<algebra-with-one over GF(2), with 2 generators>
gap> AugmentationIdealNilpotencyIndex(FD);
3
```